# Which fields are available for the &fields parameter in the Graph API /search endpoint?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2) and I was wondering which fields are available for the `&fields` parameter and also where do I find any documentation about those fields.

I could only find the Search types for the `&type` parameter in the documentation for example the `page` Search type let's you search for a page if you provide a name to be queried.

**Example request**

```
search?q=Facebook&type=page
```

**Example response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Computers/technology", 
      "name": "Facebook Engineering", 
      "id": "9445547199"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Product/service", 
      "name": "Facebook", 
      "id": "103274306376166"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Product/service", 
      "name": "Facebook Developers", 
      "id": "19292868552"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Media/news/publishing", 
      "name": "Facebook Stories", 
      "id": "114770288670819"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I now need some specified fields from this collection I know from a previous experience that I could use the `&fields` parameter to extract them or filter them out.

**Example request**

```
search?q=Facebook&type=page&fields=name, likes, location
```

**Example response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Facebook NY", 
      "likes": 71564, 
      "location": {
      "street": "770 Broadway", 
      "city": "New York", 
      "state": "NY", 
      "country": "United States", 
      "zip": "10003", 
      "latitude": 40.730901749524, 
      "longitude": -73.991377364328
      }, 
      "id": "28864583650"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Facebook London", 
      "likes": 56441, 
      "location": {
      "street": "10 Brock Street", 
      "city": "London", 
      "state": "", 
      "country": "United Kingdom", 
      "zip": "NW1 3FG", 
      "latitude": 51.5258476, 
      "longitude": -0.1394228
      }, 
      "id": "265781023507354"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Facebook Paris", 
      "likes": 29740, 
      "location": {
      "street": "", 
      "city": "Paris", 
      "state": "", 
      "country": "France", 
      "zip": "75017", 
      "latitude": 48.883443087419, 
      "longitude": 2.3023060392957
      }, 
      "id": "147424071942327"
    } 
  ]
}
```

*I used the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to do this*

**TLDR;** is there a list or documentation available for all the options/specific fields in the `&fields` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exact documentation on the search fields endpoint.

An educated guess would be that based on the type you can inspect the fields of that page.

Example, for type=page the fields available will be listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the page fields are available at that url and do you know why there's a lack of documentation for the endpoints?

Comment: Not all fields are allowed to be shown in the search fields endpoint. Have tried that. I think they are worried about privacy if they let us access too flexibly on their data.

Comment: Latest url for `page` reference is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page

Comment: You can use &metadata=1 in url to get all possible fields and their descriptions and also all possible connections urls like friends/family ect

Answer (score 9):

Although there is no complete documentation, for any element you can query
{id}?metadata=1

this will give you a full list of fields and edges that are available for that object type (as well as its type at the very bottom)

sample call: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?metadata=1

Comment: Nice! I'm new to the facebook api, and that was a great tip!